# knockout dynamic key as reference mapping , between JSON and Observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

i have tabular data retrieve from db.
being that the table is design in a non friendly label, i have to add a new object (HeaderName) to store a friendly name retrieve from another reference.

I am trying to get my raw data in the ko.observable replace with the header i have retrieve earlier for the table columns display.

is there posiblities to just map it with the ko.mapping function ? without looping it over ? 
i am wondering of the ko.mapping , key function.. trying to understand it.

With this example -> (http://jsfiddle.net/nEaSJ/ )
Data is mapped through  'children':

### in my case i have prepName that needed to be map to ColumnName

---

below is 2 of the function where i think the manipulation should happen. before i iterate it at the UI

```
var label = function (data) {
    this.label = ko.observable(data);
    //console.log(data);  //sample value = Cnv_Id

    var labeldesc = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, vm.columns);
    console.dir(labeldesc);  //Should return me  "Count Numeral Variable Identification"
}
//vm.columns (ko.observable)
      //vm.columns=[{"$id":"1","ColumnName":"Id","system_type_id":56,"primaryCol":1,"__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"$id":true,"ColumnName":true,"system_type_id":true,"primaryCol":true},"copiedProperties":{}},"isVisible":true,"HeaderName":"Id","SystemField":-1,"Visible":true}
    //,{"$id":"2","ColumnName":"Cnv_Id","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0,"__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"$id":true,"ColumnName":true,"system_type_id":true,"primaryCol":true},"copiedProperties":{}},"isVisible":true,"HeaderName":"Count Numeral Variable Id","SystemField":-1,"Visible":true},
    //{"$id":"3","ColumnName":"Cox_No","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0,"__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"$id":true,"ColumnName":true,"system_type_id":true,"primaryCol":true},"copiedProperties":{}},"isVisible":true,"HeaderName":"Cox No","SystemField":-1,"Visible":true},
    //{"$id":"4","ColumnName":"CX_Name","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0,"__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"observe":[],"mappedProperties":{"$id":true,"ColumnName":true,"system_type_id":true,"primaryCol":true},"copiedProperties":{}},"isVisible":true,"HeaderName":"CX Name","SystemField":-1,"Visible":true}]


//data input for bindSelectedModel
//data = [{"propName":"$id","propValue":"2"},{"propName":"Id","propValue":5421},{"propName":"Cnv_Id","propValue":"CV0001-1-1"},
{"propName":"Cox_No","propValue":"12"},{"propName":"CX_Name","propValue":"Exz"}]

function bindSelectedModel(data) {

  var labelmapping = {
      'propName': {
          create: function (options) {
              console.log('mapping:', options.data);
              return new label(options.data);
          }
      }
  }
  vm.selectedItemModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, labelmapping);
    vm.selectedItemHeader = vm.columns(); 
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Are you having a problem with your code?

Comment: how do i get the data.propName to be replace with the (vm.columns)HeaderName ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can see *columns* contains the "proper" names, *dataPropertiesName* contains the names of the *data* properties and data contains your view model.

So the snippet loops through each items and replaces their properties name.

```
var columns = ['FriendlyName1', 'FriendlyName2'];
var dataPropertiesName = ['Name1', 'Name2'];

var data = [{
    Name1: ko.observable(1),
    Name2: ko.observable(2)
}, {
    Name1: ko.observable(3),
    Name2: ko.observable(2)
}, {
    Name1: ko.observable(2),
    Name2: ko.observable(7)
}, ];

for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
    var item = data[index];
    item = ko.mapping.toJS(item);
    for (var propIndex = 0; propIndex < columns.length; propIndex++) {
        var value = item[dataPropertiesName[propIndex]]
        delete item[dataPropertiesName[propIndex]];
        item[columns[propIndex]] = value;
    }
    data[index] = item;
}


var result = JSON.stringify(data);

alert(result);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: is there posiblities to just map it with the ko.mapping function ?

Comment: is there posiblities to just map it with the ko.mapping function ? without looping it over ? 
i am wondering of the ko.mapping , key function.. trying to understand it.

With this example -> http://jsfiddle.net/nEaSJ/ 
Data is mapped through  'children':

in my case i have prepName that needed to be map to ColumnName

Comment: I don't think there is way to rename properties of an object with ko.mapping tools.
By using the 'key' functionality you will be able give the unique identifier of an instance. 
I also short up my fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/zULwf/2/)